# Opposite of "to put a good word in for"? "Backstab" doesn't work

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I know that when I have an associate who I think highly of and is very capable of performing the job (or person for a relationship) [s]he is pursuing, I will want to find the "recruiters" and put a good word in for my friend/associate.

What if I want to make it tough for someone to get a position? I would want to go to those "recruiters" and convince them that my associate sucks and is not cut out for it. I would be dissuading those recruiters. But what word would fit "I would be **_** my associate"? Backstabbing doesn't really cut it for me.

The same word would work in this sentence: "I feel my current bosses don't like me, and I'm afraid that they'll __ me to any prospective employer." or this one: "People think that I'm a slob that they would probably __ me to that hot girl I want to pursue."

I'm tempted to make up a word - decommend - the opposite of recommend where the direct object is that poor person you would be putting a bad word in for.

Comment: Does "badmouth" work?

Comment: Probably, but that's more general. I want a word that specifically captures the essence of preventing someone of a pursuit.

Comment: I would think *blackball* fits the bill nicely. It has expanded from the original meaning of *veto* to something very like what you are asking (at least in an employment context).

Comment: "Decommend" is, as you note, not in general circulation. The productive prefix "dis-" could be used ("disrecommend"), and most native speakers would understand immediately. Or you could rewrite in terms of "warn against".

Comment: Are you thinking of *rat on*?

Comment: **rat on** (also *North American* **rat someone out**) *informal* inform on (someone): *he refused to rat on his buddies* (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rat%2Bon___1?q=rat+on) **rat on** (also **rat out**) *informal* inform on (someone) to a person in a position of authority: *I never thought Stash would rat on me*; *men will literally choose death over ratting out another prisoner* (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/rat%2Bon%2Balso%2Brat%2Bout___1?q=rat+on+also+rat+out)

Comment: I agree with @TimLymington that _blackball_ is best, and suggest he change his comment to an answer.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: maybe *blackball* would do, after all. Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 4):

I would go for [*undermining*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undermine), see meaning 3 below:

> 1: to excavate the earth beneath : form a mine under : sap
>
> 2: to wash away supporting material from under
>
> 3: to subvert or weaken insidiously or secretly: *trying to undermine his political rivals*
>
> 4: to weaken or ruin by degrees

Answer (score 3):

**Discommend** seems to be the word you're looking for, although I can't say I've ever heard it used.

> To show disapproval of something, find fault with; To speak dissuasively of, to advise against

source: [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Adiscommend)

I think **denigrate** also works ok here, though it doesn't have the explicit connotation you want.

> to deny the importance or validity of  (denigrate their achievements)

[source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denigrate)

Comment: I really like *discommend*. I’ve never heard it used before, but I think I’ll start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Slander or sabotage would work. I like slander because it really emphasizes the spoken word as the medium for the put down.

As someone mentioned, slander is only the correct word if the spoken informtaion is false. An alternate word would be defame, which has the implication of slander, but is not necessarily truthful information.

Comment: @MετάEd sabotage can be a verb, but not of a form usable in the example sentences.

Comment: @starwed True. The problem is that you cannot "sabotage A to B", the way you can "denounce A to B" or "recommend A to B".

Comment: "Defame" has the same problem as "slander". It means to injure sb's reputation by false statements. The OP's context has nothing to do with false statements.

Comment: Defame implies slander, but not necessarily a one to one relationship

Comment: The trouble with "slander" (or other forms of defamation, e.g. libel) is that it only applies if the speech is _untrue_.  If the discommendation is justified, then it can't be slander.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common slang term in the US, *[dis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dis)* which is derived from *disrespect*

> 1. slang : to treat with disrespect or contempt : insult
> 2. slang : to find fault with : criticize
>
> *a DJ who has **dissed** every album that rapper has put out*

This term would only be used in informal conversation, not in writing or formal discussions.

Answer (score -3):

You could try 'downgrade'. You could also try to make up your own word but I feel like downgrade might be adequate for this use.

As in, Company A had their credit score downgraded.

Or, in your case

> and I'm afraid that they'll *downgrade* me to any prospective employer

It doesn't work as well in the casual sense with the hot girl because it's more business-y.

You could also try 'hold the mustard' or 'hold the sauce', which is more casual. ( I just made this up BTW )

> and I'm afraid that they'll *hold the mustard* with prospective employers
>
> People think that I'm a slob that they would probably hold the sauce with that hot girl I want to pursue.

Comment: You can't "downgrade someone *to someone else". You can downgrade them on your salary scale or other scale - but not "to someone".  Also, please note that people on this site are asking for serious answers to actual problems - ***not*** for made-up or jokey answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TrevorD. A bit stern but thanks all together. The english language, like any language, is fluid and made up phrases happen all the time. Like 'pump the brakes' for example. Also the original poster said 'I'm tempted to make up a word' which suggested to me that they might be willing to accept something made up. 

Downgrade, although not commonly used for that can definitely be used according to it's definition. Commonly accepted use and extended use of a word can be different.

Comment: OK. Maybe British use of *downgrade* is more restricted than its use wherever you are?

Comment: I'm in the US @TrevorD. Thanks for the feedback though and I'm new to this Q&A section of stackexchange. I just jumped in too eagerly I guess. I'll keep your feedback in mind when answering other questions. :-)

Comment: Welcome! You might like to look through some of the Help pages that are specific to this EL&U section of SE.